# How to correctly reference other routing files?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I meet a problem when I create route with react and react-routerd-dom v6+.

My project tree

```
my-react-app/
|-- src/
|   |-- components/
|   |-- pages/
|   |   |-- MainPage.jsx
|   |   |-- Auth/
|   |   |   |-- Login.jsx
|   |-- routes/
|   |   |-- authRoutes.jsx
|   |   |-- index.jsx
|   |-- App.jsx
|   |-- index.js
|-- public/
|   |-- index.html
|-- package.json
```

In routes folder, code of index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainPage from '../pages/MainPage';
import AuthRoutes from './authRoutes';

const AllRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
        <AuthRoutes />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default AllRoutes;
```

And the code of authRoutes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from '../pages/Auth/Login';

const AuthRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path="/auth/login" element={<Login />} />
    </>
  );
}

export default AuthRoutes;
```

The error information is

[AuthRoutes] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

##### What I have tried

1. Change `<>` and `</>` to `<React.Fragment>` and `</React.Fragment>` in authRoutes.jsx, still the same error.
2. Change `<>` and `</>` to `<Routes>` and `</Routes>` in authRoutes.jsx, still the same error.
3. Change `<Route path="/auth/login" element={<Login />} />` to `<Route path="/auth/login" element={ Login } />`, still the same error.

Please help me correct the errors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Update authRoutes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from '../pages/Auth/Login';

const AuthRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/auth/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default AuthRoutes;
```

And update index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainPage from '../pages/MainPage';
import AuthRoutes from './authRoutes';

const AllRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<AuthRoutes />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default AllRoutes;
```

It works now. But this solution gave me another question.

authRoutes.jsx returns

```
<Routes>
 <Route path="/auth/login" element={<Login />} />
</Routes>
```

When it is referenced by index.jsx, index.jsx returns

```
<Router>
 <Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<MainPage />} />
   <Route path="*" element={<AuthRoutes />} />
 </Routes>
</Router>
```

Its structure is like

```
<Router>
 <Routes>
  <Route>
  <Routes>
   <Route>
  </Routes>
 </Routes>
</Router>
```

It looks so weird.